# Why is sed changed not saved in yaml file?

Tags: linux, sed

My command

```
sed -e 's,kurtburak,JohnMarkovic,g' < values-override.yaml
```

Screen shows what I expected

```
server:
  configEnabled: true
  config:
    repositories: |
      - type: git
        url: https://github.com/JohnMarkovic/argocd.git
      - name: argo-helm
        type: helm
        url: https://argoproj.github.io/argo-helm
```

But

```
cat values-override.yaml
```

shows

```
server:
  configEnabled: true
  config:
    repositories: |
      - type: git
        url: https://github.com/kurtburak/argocd.git
      - name: argo-helm
        type: helm
        url: https://argoproj.github.io/argo-helm
```

If I change to

```
sed -i
```

got

```
sed: no input files
```

Why?

Comment: To use -i option to modify the source file.

Comment: @ElapsedSoul take  a look at my edit,now it can not see the input.

Comment: show the whole command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed -i -e 's,kurtburak,JohnMarkovic,g' values-override.yaml
```